# Nested Swift Dictionaries

Tags: swift

I want to initialize a dictionary with a dictionary nested inside like this:

```
var a = [Int:[Int:Float]]()
a[1][2] = 12
```

But I get an error:

```
(Int:[Int:Float]) does not have a member named 'subscript'
```

I've hacked at a variety of other approaches, all of them running into some kind of issue.

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own 2D dictionary like this:

```
struct Dict2D<X:Hashable,Y:Hashable,V> {
    var values = [X:[Y:V]]()
    subscript (x:X, y:Y)->V? {
        get { return values[x]?[y] }
        set {
            if values[x] == nil {
                values[x] = [Y:V]()
            }
            values[x]![y] = newValue
        }
    }
}
var a = Dict2D<Int,Int,Float>()
a[1,2] = 12
println(a[1,2]) // Optional(12.0)
println(a[0,2]) // nil
```

The point is you access the element via `a[x,y]` instead of `a[x][y]` or `a[x]?[y]`.

Answer (score 4):

It's giving you that error because your first subscript returns an optional so it may return a dictionary or nil. In the case that it returns nil the second subscript would be invalid. You can force it to unwrap the optional value by using an exlamation point.

```
var a = [1 : [ 2: 3.14]]
a[1]
a[1]![2]
```

If you aren't positive that a[1] is non-nil you may want to safely unwrap with a question mark instead.

```
var a = [1 : [ 2: 3.14]]
a[1]
a[1]?[2]
```

You can also assign using this method. (As of Beta 5)

```
var a = [Int:[Int:Float]]()
a[1] = [Int: Float]()
a[1]?[2] = 12.0
a[1]?[2] //12.0
```

Comment: well its initially going to be empty and I'll need to fill it in. I basically just want to be able to index an object with two ints and get a float out. But not a matrix because this doesn't have a predetermined size.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the best way to go about it. You'll have to make sure to initalize all of your inner dictionaries as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is with an extension to the standard dictionary:

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func updateValueForKey(key: Key, updater: ((previousValue: Value?) -> Value)) {
        let previousValue = self[key]
        self[key] = updater(previousValue: previousValue)
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var a = [Int:[Int:Float]]()
a.updateValueForKey(1) { nestedDict in
    var nestedDict = nestedDict ?? [Int:Float]()
    nestedDict[2] = 12
    return nestedDict
}
```